# Will changes made to GraphicsDevice reset after quitting application?

Tags: java, resolution, displaymode

In Java, when you change the display mode:

```
GraphicsEnvironment gd =
            GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice dev = gd.getDefaultScreenDevice();

int w = 800;
int h = 600;
int depth = dev.getDisplayMode().getBitDepth();
DisplayMode DM = new DisplayMode(w,h,depth,
                DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
dev.setDisplayMode(DM);
```

Will the changes made here remain or reset after the application has exited?
I wonder this because if you maybe made a typo, like setting the depth/resolution wrong.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @icza I haven't tried it, because I was just thinking if it could mess up my whole screen, and if the changes would be permanent (if you don't change it back again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that these changes will revert when the application is closed, which is good.

/Viktor